# Save matplotlib images directly into a bucket from a container

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I'm developing a flask app that runs on a container, from there I have to save some plots into a google cloud platform bucket.

E.G. I have the following code to plot a confusion matrix:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(target, predictions, labels=classes)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
thresh = cm.max() / 2.
for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
    plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
             horizontalalignment="center",
             color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.tight_layout()
file_name = self.data_dir + self.name + file_name
plt.savefig(file_name)
```

Which in the last line save the image in 'file_name' say file_name = 'data/my_plot.png'

This works if I run the flask app alone, but if it is inside a container, I don't have access to write permanent files, unless I bind a directory or something alike.

My plan is to save the images directly in a bucket, for that I have this code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name='models'
source_file_name='jobdesc.zip'
destination_blob_name='jobdesc.zip'
credentials = 'xx.json'

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name,credentials):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name) 

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

But in other to use this, I have to have the file saved already since I'm
just sending the path of the files I want to upload.

Is it possible to skip this step and just save the image directly from the container into the bucket?

Or is it necessary to first bind  the directory and upload the files from there?

Answer (score 2):

matplotlib can save figure into bytes, but you need to supply a `format` argument as it can no longer infer format from the file extension:

```
In [35]: import io

In [36]: buffer = io.BytesIO()

In [37]: plt.plot(range(10))
Out[37]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x102d06f4a8>]

In [39]: plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')

In [40]: buffer.getvalue()
Out[40]: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x80\x00\x00\x01\xe0\x08\x06\x00\x00\x005\xd1\xdc\xe4\x00\x00\x00\x04sBIT\x08\x08\x08\x08|\x08d\x88\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0fa\x00\x00\x0fa\x01\xa8?\xa7i\x00\x00\x009tEXtSoftware\x00matplotlib version 3.0.0, http://matplotlib.org/\xa8\xe6\x1d\xf0\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xed\xddyx\x94\x85\xbd\xf6\xf1{f\xb2\xaf\x90@\xc2\x16 \xac\x01\x02Y\x00
```

Then use [`upload_from_string`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.upload_from_string) instead of `upload_from_file` to upload the result of `buffer.getvalue()` onto google blob storage.